# What are 'r_[]' and "basename = 'arc'" lines in Python code

Tags: python, numpy

There is an example of Python code [here](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Least_Squares_Circle). I cannot find any explanation of the following lines:

```
x = r_[36, 36, 19, 18, 33, 26]
y = r_[14, 10, 28, 31, 18, 26]
basename = 'arc'
```

Please tell me how it works. Or refer to any info page. Thank you.

Comment: I did not know a name for this. How I suppose to ask this question? I even could not search it...

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed. It looked like a legitimate question. Maybe not lumping the two unrelated questions would have helped though. basename='arc' is nothing more than a string assignment, it could be subsequently used for anything that a string is used for, in this case helping to name a file.

Comment: @Stuart yes, I can see that now. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`r_` is numpy magic: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html

`basename` is used later to generate a filename:

```
...
# basename is actually set to "circle" ("arc" is commented out) in that example.
# this saves the figure to "circle_residu2.png" or "circle_residu1.png"
p.savefig('%s_residu%d.png' % (basename, 2 if residu2 else 1))
```

Comment: numpy magic ... nice.

Comment: `basename` does not "generate" a filename; here, it's just a variable name.

Comment: it is _used_ to generate a filename later. (`p.savefig('%s_residu%d.png' % (basename, a_digit)`). Sorry if that was unclear, reworded.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [NumPy for Matlab Users page](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#rangeliteralNotes) `r_` is an object created to allow for ranges of numbers to be created with a notation like Matlab.
i.e.

> In MATLAB®, 0:5 can be used as both a range literal and a 'slice' index (inside parentheses); however, in Python, constructs like 0:5 can only be used as a slice index (inside square brackets).

Check [the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) for more info on how `r_` works.